# issue - dynamically populating checkbox group from database(MYSQL) in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I have an issue populating checkbox group dynamically from database(MYSQL) in extjs 4. Below is the code i tried by searching forums. Please advise what needs to be done to get this working.

(i)  I have an ArrayStore as below:

```
           var checkboxArray1 = [];
     var arrayStore=   new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
      autoLoad:false,
      proxy: {
             type: 'rest',
             url: 'xxxxxxx',
             reader: {
                 type: 'json',
                 root: 'doThisStore'
             }  
      },
      fields : ['vcName','vcId'],
      listeners: {                                                                           

             load: function(t, records, options) {                                                  

                 for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {  

                   checkboxArray1.push({name: records[i].data.vcId, boxLabel: records[i].data.vcName});  
                   alert(checkboxArray1[i].name);
                   alert(checkboxArray1[i].boxLabel);
                 }                                                                                  
             }                                                                                      
         }      
     });
```

(ii) I have 'fieldset' as below:

```
{
                        xtype : 'fieldset',
                        title : "Systems",
                        collapsed:false,
                        checkboxToggle: true,
                        anchor : '100%',
                        defaults : {
                            msgTarget : 'side',
                            allowBlank : true
                        },
                        items:{
                           xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                         fieldLabel: 'dothis',
                         columns: 3,
                         vertical: true,
                         items: checkboxArray1

                    }},
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

First Give Id To items of checkboxgroup and then Use that id as

```
Ext.getCmp('Your Id').add(CheckBoxArray1);
```

Comment: It works but add() is private method and extjs doesn't grantees functionality of private method, and so in next version of extjs framework maybi add() functionality changes, and add not work correctly